# Printing error message from servlet to jsp in gwt application

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Printing error message from servlet to jsp in gwt application

I am using printing the error message in my gwt application by jsp like below.

//Servlet code

```
if (validateBranchId == false) {
      UserMessagesAndErrors ume = ThreadLocalObjects.
                         getThreadLocalUserMessagesAndErrors().get();
      ume.addError("Branch Id value is not correct");
      RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
                         getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/errors.jsp");
      dispatcher.forward(req, res);         
    }
```

//Jsp code(errors.jsp)

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" isELIgnored="false" %>    
<%@ page import="com.veersoft.util.ThreadLocalObjects" %>
```

As per the above code if my branch id is not present in the objectify datastore, validateBranchId  is false, SO my ume (usermessagesAndErrors) has to print the message in the jsp but instead it is not printing the message in the jsp. 
Any body have idea please let me know.

```
<%@ page import="com.veersoft.gwt.shared.error.UserMessagesAndErrors" %>     
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>     

errors!    
<%    
    UserMessagesAndErrors ume = ThreadLocalObjects.getUserMessagesAndErrorsObj();
    List<String> errors = ume.getErrors();    
    for (String error : errors) {    
        out.println(error + "<BR/>");    
    }     

    List<String> messages = ume.getMessages();    
    for (String message : messages) {    
        out.println(message + "<BR/>");    
    }    
%>
```

Comment: Can any body have idea about this issue? It is printing in the console System.out.println("") but not printing in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In the servlet :

```
ume.addError("Branch Id value is not correct");
req.setAttribute("ume",ume); // add it to the request
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ...
```

In the jsp :

```
UserMessagesAndErrors ume = (UserMessagesAndErrors) request.getAttribute("ume");
List<String> errors = ume.getErrors();
//etc
```

But you should avoid scriptlets altogether in jsp - use EL.